# Getting to specific lines of a text file using ANSI functions

Tags: c, csv, crud, fgets, ansi-c

in trying to create a function in c which can get to a specific line in a CSV file (similar to getline()). I'm only allowed to use the ANSI 89/99 standard. Here is what i have wrote so far:

```
char * getline(FILE * fi,size_t line_length,size_t line_number)
{

size_t i;
char * aux_string;
char * p;
if (fi==NULL)
    return NULL;

if ((aux_string = malloc(line_length*sizeof(char)))==NULL)
    return NULL;

i=0;
while(fgets(aux_string,line_length,fi)!=NULL||feof(fi)!=0)
 {

    if (i==line_number)
    {

        if ((p=strchr(aux_string,'\n'))!=NULL)
        {
            *p='\0';
        }

        return aux_string;  
    }
    i++;

 }
return NULL;
}
```

This works fairly ok for a single call to getline(). However, if the function is called like in the example below:

```
puts(getline(file_a,MAX_LENGTH,0));
puts(getline(file_a,MAX_LENGTH,0));
```

It outputs the line in the file immediately below, as well as the desired line. 
How can I avoid this? What could be causing this? Thanks.

Comment: Get rid of `feof(fi)!=0` condition

Comment: `puts(getline(...));rewind(file_a);puts(getline(...));` [posix rewind()](https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/rewind.html)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`FILE*` remembers position inside the file where you ended. So the second time you call `fread` the file has already read the first line, so you start reading from the second line. You need to `fseek(fi, 0, SEEK_SET)` rewind the file to the beginning.

```
char * getline(FILE * fi,size_t line_length,size_t line_number)
{
    if (fseek(fi, 0, SEEK_SET) != 0) {
          // handle error
     }
     // rest of your function
```

Notes:

- [rewind](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/io/rewind) is equivalent to `fseek(.., 0, SEEK_SET)`, but offers no error handling (weii, except `ferror` that is).
- `puts(getline(file_a,MAX_LENGTH,0));` leaks memory allocated inside `getline`. You should `char *pnt = getline(...); puts(pnt); free(pnt)` always remember to pick out the trash.
- The `feof(fi)!=0` condition from inside the `while` loop looks redundant. If the file has no more lines, the `fgets` will tell you about it.
- I would advise to rename the function to some `mygetline` or such, not to confuse others. The function `getline` is already a [POSIX function](https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/getdelim.html) that's been around for very long.